# std::vector use of const_iterator terminates program

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator

```
Distance distance(const vector<long> &x, const vector <short> &y)
{
    Distance total = 0.0;
    Distance diff;

    vector <long >::const_iterator cpx=x.begin(); //terminates at this line

    vector <short>::const_iterator cpy=y.begin();
    vector <long>::const_iterator cpx_end=x.end();
    for(;cpx!=cpx_end;++cpx,++cpy){
        diff = *cpx - *cpy;
        total += (diff * diff);
    }
    return total;
}
```

distance is long long int.

my code terminates when i try to assign the const iterator with begin of vector?
why is this happening?
vectors are initialized with zero.

Comment: Please provide the code (minimally) that calls this function aswell as any error message you get when the program terminates.  Have you debugged in to this?

Comment: If you mean "memset(&vec, 0, sizeof(vec))" with "vectors initialized with zero", then that's your problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB dont mind but are you blind cant you see cpx and cpy are iterators declared and assigned in the same line of code..

Comment: @shobi: Very true, apologies!

Comment: @KerrekSB its ok, sometimes it happens to every one, and sorry for my rude comment... :)

Comment: @shobi: No worries -- it was really I who was out of line. (I was still waiting for the coffee to run through.) In answer to your question: The problem probably lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing invalid in your code per se. Apparently `x` vector was somehow damaged before you call `distance`, either it's lifetime was over or you've got memory corrpution or some other UB. E.g. anything like this:

```
vector<long> &getData()
{
  vector<long> data;
  // fill data
  return data;
}

// ...

distance(getData(), y);
```

```
vector<long> *data = new vector<long>();
// fill data

delete data;

distance(*data, y);
```

```
long data[n] = ...;
vector<long> x(n);
memcpy(&x, data, sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]));
```

```
vector<long> *data = 0;

distance(*data, y);
```

And there could be much more other cases, anyhow, the solution is to check where `x` comes from and where it is destroyed or becomes invalid.